# Error when deploying Pivotal cloud foundry app

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

[image: Error]

So I simply followed the instructions given here :https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry/deploy-the-sample-app

I pushed the app successfully but when I put the route in my web browser, it gives me an error as shown in the screenshot. 
I haven't made any changes to the sample file I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue-
The folder which contained all files was nested inside a redundant folder.
Instead of having files in **folder xyz**, I had my files in **folder xyz which was nested in folder xyz**

This happens when you download a zipped version and unzip it.